# Retrieve all records from Berkeley DB in java

Tags: java, berkeley-db

Is there an easy way to get all key/value pairs in a given database? I read somewhere that I can use a Cursor but I couldn't find a real example of it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here](http://download.oracle.com/berkeley-db/docs/je/1.5.3/GettingStartedGuide/Positioning.html) is an example from oracle.

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate the Cursor and add all key/value to a Map